# Does $\operatorname{Hom}(M,T)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(N, T)$ for all $A$-modules $T$ mean $M\cong N$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

The question is contained in title, I'm working with $A$-modules $M$ and $N$. I feel like Yoneda's lemma is what I'm looking for but it applies to functors into the category of sets, whereas $\operatorname{Hom}$ stays in the category of $A$-modules. Another idea is that if we switch the arguments, we can use that $\operatorname{Hom}(A, M)\cong M$ and be instantly done. I fear that something equally trivial can be done here that I'm missing. Thanks for any help you may have!

Comment: If you mean functorially in $T$, then yes. This is just Yoneda's lemma. If they are isomorphic as functors to $A$-modules, then they are also isomorphic as functors to $mathbf{Set}$, and so Yoneda applies.

Comment: "Hom stays in the category of $A$-modules." Well, then you mean an internal hom. And this only works when $A$ is commutative. Do you assume this? Do you want to require naturality in $T$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I do assume $A$ is commutative. Also, I don't think naturality in $T$ is implied in general, correct me if I'm wrong, but your comment made me realize that it may be true in my case.

Comment: My answer is for the case that $A$ is a field. What about $A=\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. abelian groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if we require the isomorphism to be natural in $T$.

If we don't require this, the answer depends on set theory - at least for vector spaces, which may be regarded as the simplest examples of modules.

By [Easton's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem) it is consistent with ZFC that there are different infinite cardinals numbers $\lambda,\mu$ such that $2^\lambda = 2^\mu$. Let $K$ be a finite field, let $V$ be a $\lambda$-dimensional vector space and let $W$ be a $\mu$-dimensional vector space. Then $\dim(V^*) = |K|^\lambda=2^\lambda$ by the [Erdős-Kaplansky Theorem](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_d%27Erd%C5%91s-Kaplansky) and similarly $\dim(W^*) = 2^\mu$. Hence, $V \not\cong W$, but $V^* \cong W^*$. If $U$ is any vector space over $K$, say of dimension $\kappa$, it follows $\underline{\hom}(V,U) \cong (V^*)^\kappa \cong (W^*)^\kappa \cong \underline{\hom}(V,U)$.

Conversely, if $K$ is a finite field and $\forall U(\underline{\hom}(V,U) \cong \underline{\hom}(W,U)) \Rightarrow V \cong W$ holds in the category of vector spaces over $K$, then $\lambda \mapsto 2^\lambda$ is injective. But this is independent from ZFC.

Comment: Really nice counterexample, thanks for the thoroughness

Comment: Also for context, in my case I was trying to prove that $\left(\oplus_i M_i\right)\otimes N\cong\oplus_i\left(M_i\otimes N\right)$ categorically, so I took $\operatorname{Hom}(\left(\oplus_i M_i\right)\otimes N, P)$ for arbitrary $P$ and used the adjunction of tensor product and Hom. So in my case at least, I'm pretty confidant the isomorphism is natural.